# How do I name variables dynamically in C#?

Tags: c#, variables, dynamic-data

Is there a way to dynamically name variables?

What I need to do is take a list of variable names from an input file and create variables with those names.  Is this possible?

Something like:

```
Variable <dynamic name of variable here> = new Variable(input);
```

Assume that I already have the `Variable` class taken care of, and the name of the variable is contain in a string called `strLine`.

Comment: Are you talking about generating code to be compiled or doing something dynamically in run-time? Please tell us your use-case and reasons for wanting to do this.

Comment: Why would you even want to do this? How does it even matter? Even if you need to output the name of the variable somewhere, you can store the name in `Variable` class.

Comment: can you explain why did you post this question ? there is maybe right ways to do what you want

Comment: The reason I want to do this is I'm creating an interpreter for a made up programming language, and I need to be able to store variables for said language.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a `Dictionary<string, Variable>`.

e.g.

```
var vartable = new Dictionary<string, Variable>();
vartable[strLine] = new Variable(input);
```

Answer (score 5):

C# 4.0, using the `dynamic` objects:

```
dynamic d = new ExpandoObject();
((IDictionary<string, object>)d)["MyProperty"] =  5;
int val = d.MyProperty; // 5
```

Answer (score 1):

No, but you could use a `Dictionary<string, Variable>`, and then you can refer to each variable by its quoted name.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, but what you're looking to do is begging for a Dictionary use:

```
Dictionary<object, object> d = new Dictionary<string, object>();
d.Add("Variable1", value1);
d.Add("Variable2", value2);
d.Add("Variable3", value3);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one,user json to serialize and deserialize:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
     public class Program
     {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            object newobj = new object();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
              List<int> temp = new List<int>();

              temp.Add(i);
              temp.Add(i + 1);

               newobj = newobj.AddNewField("item_" + i.ToString(), temp.ToArray());
            }

       }

    }

    public static class DynamicExtention
    {
        public static object AddNewField(this object obj, string key, object value)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            string data = js.Serialize(obj);

            string newPrametr = "\"" + key + "\":" + js.Serialize(value);

            if (data.Length == 2)
           {
               data = data.Insert(1, newPrametr);
            }
          else
            {
                data = data.Insert(data.Length-1, ","+newPrametr);
            }

            return js.DeserializeObject(data);
        }
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable names should be known at compile time. If you intend to populate those names dynamically at runtime you could use a [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).

```
 var variables = List<Variable>();
 variables.Add(new Variable { Name = input1 });
 variables.Add(new Variable { Name = input2 });
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

No.  You can load them into a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) object, however.  This allows you to still reference them (somewhat) using a name, which is a bit easier than using an Index, as you would with an Array or ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

I would use some sort of keyed collection, like a hashtable, dictionary, or list of structures with the name. You can then refer to the variable by name:

```
var value = variableDictionary["MyVariableName"];
var value = variableHashtable["MyVariableName"];
var value = variableList.First(x=>x.Name == "MyVariableName");
```

There is no other way to dynamically "name" a variable.

Answer (score -1):

No. Use an array, otherwise you can't do this.