# Dictionary With Value "Variable"

Tags: c#, variables, dictionary

I am hoping to create a dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Variable> dict = new Dictionary<string, Variable>
```

In this thread [How do I name variables dynamically in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033675/how-do-i-name-variables-dynamically-in-c) the following code example was voted up and accepted as the answer to the question:

```
var vartable = new Dictionary<string, Variable>();
vartable[strLine] = new Variable(input);
```

However, when I try to do the same thing I get this error Message:

```
The type or namespace name 'Variable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I have been unable to find a namespace that fixes this.  Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: What is `Variable`? You're referencing it like a type. The error indicates that you don't have a `using` statement that imports that type for use. You also may have to add a project reference to whatever library contains `Variable`.

Comment: Look in the original question you reference. He states that he has already created his own `Variable` class. http://cl.ly/image/3F012q2P1L3V

Comment: Variable is the name of the object that you want a dynamic name for.

Comment: @MarkRucker: [Smacks forehead]  You're right.  I read the question heading and the answer and overlooked the implementation details.  I was rushing.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: No problem. We all get a little spacey sometimes. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Variable` is meant to be your own class, so you have to define it first.

Answer (score 2):

There's no type called `Variable`. It's just an example type name.