# Dictionary With Variables As Values

Tags: c#, variables, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dictionary With Value “Variable”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008203/dictionary-with-value-variable)

I have some highly coupled code that I am trying to decouple.  If I could make a Dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<string, var> dict = new Dictionary<string, var>
```

a lot of coupling could be fixed.  One poster in another thread seems to have found a solution using a Variable class but he/she didn't post any details of this class and I can't think of how to do it.

EDIT:

Basically, instead of:

```
string transit = <string value>;
```

I would like to be able to write:

```
string dict["Transit"] = <string value>;
```

Where I have already done:

```
Dictionary<string, var> dict = new Dictionary<string, var>()
{
    {"Transit", transit}
};
```

This probably isn't possible but any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Difficult to give you a constructive answer without seeing the code you want to decouple - you are proposing a solution instead of giving us the problem and having us propose solutions.

Comment: honestly, it's hard to say what *exactly* you're asking about..

Comment: Unclear. Looks like you want to store something by reference but we'd need much more context.

Comment: I just edited my post to show why I am trying to achieve.

Comment: All I see is a normal class field - why would putting it into a `Dictionary` help? It is still unclear from your post what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the var keyword first. var is simply a declarative shortcut. If you don't know the type of value being stored, use object, with the understanding that you'll have to cast the return values and boxing may be a performance concern (in extreme cases). In that case, dmck's answer is perfectly valid.

Comment: is it a dupplicate post of your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008203/dictionary-with-value-variable ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would do the trick:

```
public class Variable
{
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then he could do what he is asking, namely:

```
Dictionary<string, Variable> dict = new Dictionary<string, Variable>()
{
    {"Transit", new Variable()}
}

dict["Transit"].Value = "transit"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer (you're right, I was assuming it was more complicated) and thanks for the support.  What bugs me about the downvoters is that they don't leave a comment.  I mean, it's a forum, if you can't be constructive what are you doing here?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to add even IEnumerable,IQueryable variables to your dictionary.
Object class is the super class and can store anything and can be cast to anything.

```
var myVar = new { name="john",lastname="smith"}; // or any linq expression
Dictionary<string, Object> asd = new Dictionary<string, object>();
asd.Add("mykey", myVar);
```