# How to create class variable name dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, class

[image]

```
class CarMaker
{
    public void MakeNewCar(int carCount)
    {
        string[] names = new string[carCount];
        Random random = new Random();            
        for (int i = 0; i < carCount; i++)
        {
            int randomNum = random.Next(0, 3);
            Car **howCanIDo** = new Car(null, (EModels)randomNum, (EColor)randomNum);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what are you trying to achieve by doing so? what is the logic you want?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/5033731/6923146

Comment: why do you want to?  What are you going to do with the cars? I suspect you want a list and you can add each to the list without each having a unique name

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create dynamic variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857773/create-dynamic-variable-name)

Comment: What you are trying to do is impossible, but you can achieve the same functionality with arrays, dictionaries...

Answer (score 3):

By the collection `names` I assume you want to "hold" all the "names" (actually the references) to the `Car` objects you create in the loop. What you could do is instead have an array of type `Car` and add the items to it:

```
Car[] cars = new Car[carCount];
Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < carCount; i++)
{
    int randomNum = random.Next(0, 3);
    cars[i] = new Car(null, (EModels)randomNum, (EColor)randomNum);
}
```

And maybe even more convenient would be to just use lists:

```
List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
for (int i = 0; i < carCount; i++)
{
    int randomNum = random.Next(0, 3);
    cars.Add(new Car(null, (EModels)randomNum, (EColor)randomNum));
}
```